# Teaching sign languages as other languages, by the Internet?

Tags: online-learning, sign-language

Are there sites that teach **sign languages** through gamification? Like Duolingo, Babbel, etc?

Or, alternatively, are there researches that prove or deny the possibility of teaching sign languages online (or self-study), either with or without employing the gamification?

Comment: "Researches" is a bit strong as a word. I would prefer "with" gamification though.

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning.SE! I took my liberty to suggest an edit to make the question more objective and based on the facts. In general, "do you think that…" is a "red flag" here at StackExchange, so let's get rid of it.

Comment: You are really nice. And I thank you for your edit. A lot of people are very aggressive on StackEchange, but your edit is welcome. I just wanted to precise my ideas about "researches" and "gamification".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are websites where you can learn a sign language, though this normally does not involve gamification.

**American Sign Language (ASL)**:

- [Sign Language 101](http://www.signlanguage101.com/).
- [Learn Sign Language Online (Rocket Languages)](https://learnsignlanguage.online/).
- [Start ASL](https://www.startasl.com/learn-asl-online) (see also this [unit](https://www.startasl.com/learn-sign-language-online-asl1_html)).

**British Sign Language**:

- British-Sign.co.uk: [Introducing British Sign Language: Online Signing Course](http://www.british-sign.co.uk/learn-online-british-sign-language-course/)

**German Sign Language**:

- [Schnupperkurs Deutsche Gebärdensprache](http://www.visuelles-denken.de/Schnupperkurs.html): this is only a very basic course.
- [Gebärden lernen](http://www.gebaerdenlernen.de/): this site even has a [dictionary with sign language videos](http://www.gebaerdenlernen.de/index.php?article_id=87).
- [gebaerdensprache-lernen.de](http://www.gebaerdensprache-lernen.de/) doesn't have pointers to online courses.

**Swiss Sign Language**:

- [Online Gebärdensprache-Lexikon](http://www.gebaerdenlexikon.ch/): this is not a course but a reference work.
- [Schnupperkurs Gebärdensprache](http://www.gebaerden-sprache.ch/informationen-zur-gebaerdensprache/schnupperkurs-gebaerdensprache/index.html).
- Schweizerischer Gehörlosenbund: [Online-Lexikon](http://signsuisse.sgb-fss.ch/): covers Deutschschweizerische Gebärdensprache DSGS (sign language of the German-speaking part of Switzerland), Langue des signes française LSF (French sign language) and Lingua italiana dei segni LIS (Italian sign language).

**French sign language**:

- [lecons - LangueSignes](https://sites.google.com/site/languesignes/lecons).
- [10 applications mobiles pour apprendre la langue des signes](http://www.francosourd.com/profiles/blogs/10-apps-pour-apprendre-la-langue-des-signes): this is not a course but an article from 2013 that lists 10 mobile applications for learning sign language.

I could go on listing websites for other sign languages - it is not clear from the question which sign language the OP is interested in.

Comment: Thank you! So you think one can learn alone? For the gamification, I hope it'll come!

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE I have no idea whether you can learn sign language on your own. You can learn individual signs, but you also need to learn to recognise them when they are quickly strung together, and that is much more difficult.